# Flutter getting data from firestore using collectionGroup

Tags: flutter, geofirestore

Am creating an app which will display content based on user location. For this am using the Geoflutterfire package to query the data from firestore. The app returns data as desired when I use a single document field .for example

```
stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
      var collectionReference = firestore
          .collection("content")
         .doc("onecontentid")
         .collection("allcontents");
      return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
          center: center, radius: rad, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
    });
```

However I need to stream all documents from the "allcontents" sub collection and to achieve this tried using collectionGroup like this

```
stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
          var collectionReference = firestore
              
             .collectionGroup("allcontents");
          return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
              center: center, radius: rad, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
        });
```

which does not return any data.

My streambuilder for displaying the data looks like this

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
              if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                  snapshots.hasData) {
Do stuff}else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
```

For the first case(single doc query) it is able to retrieve data(Do stuff) From firestore For the second case(collectionGroup) it only shows the circular progress indicator.

Comment: The `GeoFlutterFire`'s collectionRef takes `Query` type as input, so your code looks good and should work. In handling the `streambuilder` are you checking the `error` state? and manually check the data in firestore as well.

Comment: Please elaborate on the  "are you checking the error state?" because am not getting any errors

Comment: `if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active)` similar to this you have to check for error `if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.error)` and update the result in screen. Now, for any state other than success its coded to show the progress indicator.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the an error message saying " Error : Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. (firestore/permission-denied)." any solutions for this

Comment: updated all in my answer. It may give workarounds for others too!

Answer (score 0):

The `GeoFlutterFire`'s collectionRef takes `Query` type as input, so your code looks good and should work. While handling the `streambuilder` result you have to check for error

> if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.error) { // Error state }

and update the result in screen. Now, for any state other than success its coded to show the progress indicator.

Update for Permission-denied Error:

This may because of the firestore security rules. I recommend this [Firestore Security Rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) reference, so that you can write more secure rules that match your application needs.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve it. The issue was with my security rules and indexes in firestore